# How to integrate customized topBar component in react-admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have the customized new AppBar component, i want to show newly customized AppBar in my page instead of old AppBar.

I want to use new appBar like below mentioned link.

https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-a-primary-search-field

How to use this New AppBar in my page instead of old one.?

Comment: Let me understand, you have 2 AppBars (new and old) and you want a way to programatically switch between AppBars?

Comment: Yes. let me explain. im using react-admin and here is a default AppBar is there. now i wish to change this AppBar like above mentioned the link know like that. so i created the new AppBar component and now i dont know how to integrate to layout exactly you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize `react-admin`'s `appBar` you should override `layout` property in this way:

```
// in src/App.js
import MyLayout from './MyLayout';

const App = () => (
    <Admin layout={MyLayout} ...>
        // ...
    </Admin>
);
```

And then:

```
// in src/MyLayout.js
import { Layout } from 'react-admin';
import MyAppBar from './MyAppBar';

const MyLayout = (props) => <Layout
    {...props}
    appBar={MyAppBar}
    ...
/>;

export default MyLayout;
```

Finally, in `src/MyAppBar.js` you could use the `app-bar-with-a-primary-search-field`. That's it.

For more info, you could see [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html).